# How to access a row of a C++ char matrix?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, char

I am relearning C++ after many years of matlab. Here is some code that I wrote

```
char  couts[3][20]={"Area of Rectangle: ","Area of Triangle: ","Area of Ellipse: "};
char C[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  C=couts[i];
  cout << C;
  //code that calculates and couts the area
}
```

clearly this is the wrong way of getting that row of couts to print, but after trying many variations and googling I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. :(

Comment: You need `strcpy(C, couts[i]);`, but as you're using C++ you should rather use `std::string` and not bother anymore with the old C functions such as `strcpy` etc. The same for raw arrays, use rather std containers such as `std::array`, `std::vector` etc.

Comment: `char* C;` lets you do the assignment you want... But why not output directly? (`std::cout << couts[i];`)

Comment: If you don't want to modify the strings anyway: `char const* const couts[3] = { ... }; char const* C;`

Answer (score 2):

Use `string`s or even `string_view`s in this case, not char arrays. You are not copying the string in `C`, so the `cout` doesn't work. In modern C++ (C++17), this would be instead:

```
constexpr std::string_view couts[] = {"Area of Rectangle: ","Area of Triangle: ","Area of Ellipse: "};
std::string_view C;
for (auto s: couts) {
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

This probably the only place I would write a C-style array and not use `std::array`, as the number of elements may change in the future.

Comment: I would say, `string_view` is so fit for this problem. But I suggest you post a link introducing this class, for the OPis not likely to know it.

Comment: ...and it's C++17, which the OP may not have.

Comment: Agreed, added the mention of C++17.

Answer (score 2):

You probbaly should use C++ features and not old C idioms:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

const std::array<std::string, 3> couts{ "Area of Rectangle: ","Area of Triangle: ","Area of Ellipse: " };

int main()
{  
  std::string C;
  for (int i = 0; i < couts.size(); i++) {
    C = couts[i];
    std::cout << C << "\n";
    //code that calculates and couts the area
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats the significance of creating the const outside of the main?

Comment: @Abijah there' s no need to change the elements of this "array"

Comment: @Abijah this is standard C/C++. Outside of main it's _a global_ variable, inside it's 
a _local_ variable, google ""c global vs local variables"" for more information and/or read it up in your C/C++ text book.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version using the [C++17 deduction guides for std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides) combined with [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) letting you use range based for-loops etc. on both the `std::array` and the `std::string_view`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr std::array couts = {
    std::string_view{"Area of Rectangle: "},
    std::string_view{"Area of Triangle: "},
    std::string_view{"Area of Ellipse: "}
};

int main() {
    for(auto& C : couts) {
        for(auto ch : C) {
            std::cout << ch; // output one char at a time
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```